# emacs why do I have hashes at the ends of my file names i.e. #test.c#

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs 22.2.1 on Ubuntu 9.04.

Every time I open a file and work on it, and then when I list the files in the directory in the terminal I see hashes at the ends of each file.

i.e.

```
#test.c#
#test.h#
```

Why is this and how can I remove them?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a backup (autosave) file. Emacs should remove them when it finishes editing the file, unless it dies  or you kill it without saving the files. It's better not to remove these files since if you do, you cannot recover if Emacs should crash for some reason. When you start Emacs again you can recover the file with M-x recover-this-file to recover it from the backup.

Answer (score 5):

These are autosave files.
Have a look at this [link](http://amitp.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-move-autosave-and-backup-files.html) to change the files to be in a different directory.
Have a look at this

Answer (score 3):

You have encountered the feature named "autosave". It saves modified buffers that have not been saved by the user for a while.

I have seen people disable it or change the location of the autosaved buffers to a temporary directory. You can also get more info [there](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Auto%20Save%20Control), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs performs a timely backup so you can always have the changes you've made (minus the last 5 minutes of your work) in case of a crash. You can remove it by this command from your working directory `rm #*`

Comment: Just careful if you have other files beginning with a # there. Rather unlikely, but there you go...

Comment: If you really don't like these files, you can configure Emacs not to create them or to create them elsewhere. That's much better than executing a dangerous command periodically in your precious directory. Although it would be funny to lose your working files because of autosave and a typo :)

Comment: And there I was thinking I had the cleverest solution and would surely get some upvotes. But these guys are correct. Make sure you don't have any files starting with `#`

Comment: You will probably have to remove the files with this:
rm \#*

Answer (score 1):

It's a recovery file that emacs creates when you haven't saved your file in a while (but only if it contains unsaved text). As soon as you save your file the recover file is removed. If emacs should crash before you can save, the file can be recovered with M-x recover-file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing these autosave files, I recommend placing them in a hidden directory. They are cheap insurance against data loss.

On Emacs 28 running on Ubuntu linux, I have the following lines in my `~/.emacs` config file:

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".", "~/.emacs-saves" t)))
```

Additionally, I use this to move the backup files (Those that look like `filename~`) as well:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs-saves")))
(setq backup-by-copying t)
```

Note that you might have a [different config file location](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), this is perfectly fine. If you find `~/.emacs` does not exist, then try `~/.emacs.el`, `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, or `~/.config/emacs/init.el`.